# Let $p \in S^2$ compute $span(p)^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $p \in S^2$ compute $span(p)^{\perp}$

I know that $\mathbb{R}^3=span(p) \oplus span(p)^{\perp}$ therefore $dim(span(p)^{\perp}=2$ then it is only necessary to find two l.i elements of $span(p)^{\perp}$ to characterize it, for example in $S^1$ it is easy to see that if $p=(p_1,p_2) \in S^1$ then $(-p_2,p_1) \in span(p)^{\perp}$ it follows that
$span((-p_1,p_2))=span((p_1,p_2))^{\perp}$ but i have problems to find these two elements i try with $(-p_2,p_1,0)$ and $(0,-p_3,p_2)$ but not works

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you mentioned in the 2-dimensional case comes from the fact that a vector $v=(x,y)$ perpendicular to $p=(p_1,p_2)$ satisfies the equation $\langle v,p \rangle = 0$, i.e., their inner product is $0$. You can plug-in the vector $(-p_2, p_1)$ and see that it indeed satisfies this equation. The same holds in the 3-dimensional case: a vector $v=(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ if $\langle v,p \rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow xp_1+yp_2+zp_3 = 0$. So you may completely describe the space you are looking for by
$$\operatorname{span}(p^\perp)=\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 : xp_1+yp_2+zp_3=0 \}.$$